# How to store a dynamically typed value in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, dynamic-typing

The SQLite FAQ states that [SQLite uses dynamic typing](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q2). But I can not find a description how to write a dynamically typed value into the database. From Oracle I know the [SYS.ANYDATA](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/anydata.php) type but I can not find anything similar in the SQLite documentation.

How to store a dynamically typed value in a SQLite database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify a type constraint for a column.

Rather than something like:

```
CREATE TABLE example (x ANY)
```

You only need to use

```
CREATE TABLE example (x)
```

This results in a column with a type affinity of NONE.

> A column with affinity NONE does not prefer one storage class over another and no attempt is made to coerce data from one storage class into another.

See Type Affinity on https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

And, for bonus, the corresponding function for `SYS.ANYDATA.getTypeName(X)` is `typeof(X)`:

> The typeof(X) function returns a string that indicates the datatype of the expression X: "null", "integer", "real", "text", or "blob".

From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: I was searching for something more complicated, I did not expected that it will be that easy ;-)